# Wordpress mod_rewrite within a plugin?

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I tried several mod_rewrite but I asking your help, because this is a complicated matter.

Wordpress has its own permalink structure that uses mod rewrite to make the url’s search engine friendly.

I have 2 plugins.
1. Turns a page into a subdirectory. So domain.com/page/ turns into page.domain.com
2. The second one is a forum that creates pages such as /?mingleforumaction=viewforum&f=2.0 and ?mingleforumaction=viewtopic&t=23.0

How can I turn the current

```
http://page.domain.com/?mingleforumaction=viewtopic&t=23.0
```

to

```
http://page.domain.com/title-of-the-forum-topic/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to ask plugin author? Are you sure your plugins will handle such structure? If yes, then why there is no mod_rewrite rules shipped with them?

Comment: The author does not know how to do this. He basically took a old plugin that was no longer supported and updated it to work with Mingle. So he is not the full-developer, but thankfully made it working again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it based solely on the topic title, those aren't unique. You could, however, do
`http://page.domain.com/23.0/title-of-the-forum-topic/`
where 23.0 is obviously the value that `t` would be set to in the query string.

**Edit**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/topic/([0-9\.]+)/ /?mingleforumaction=viewtopic&t=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

openid does not let me login from home because of a different IP, but I am the same person as the topic starter:

@spartan018
How can that be done?

@FractalizeR
The developer http://cartpauj.com/projects/mingle-forum-plugin/ used an older forum plugin and does not have the knowledge (or perhaps time to learn) to rewrite the plugin for it to have mode_rewrite rules shipped with in of have the plugin work with the permalink structure of wordpress. So I was hoping to help him, but got stuck myself because normal .htaccess mod_rewrite do not seem to work and it is based on an already existing wordpress mod_rewrite. That is why I asked for help :)